# Linux - symlink between mtd partition and user data from mount location

Tags: linux, symlink, ln

Is it possible to create a symbolic link between NAND/NOR mtd partition and a file from  mounted partition (e.g., ln -s /tmp/mnt/linux.bin /dev/mtdblock1)

Answer (score 0):

There are no limits for symlinks (just for hardlinks). As a consequence a symlink may not work ("dangling symlink").